# how can i publish my application in app brain market?

Tags: android, google-play

i develop one application in android i want to see my app in app brain please help me tell me how can i publish my application in appbrain i.e.., below link.

```
http://www.appbrain.com/
```

i didn't  use any permissions in android manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.org.mmts"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/mmts_icon"
            android:label="myproject"

            >
            <activity
                android:label="myproject" 
                android:name=".AndroidtabActivity" 
              >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.org.mmts.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name=".Touch" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.org.mmts.Touch" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
             android:name=".InfoPage" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.org.mmts.InfoPage" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name="com.org.mmts.Display" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.org.mmts.Display" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Read How to get started with the AppBrain SDK at http://www.appbrain.com/info/sdk. Its clear that you must need to publish your app at Android market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppBrain is not a marketplace, it is a website that periodically scrapes Android Market and displays that content.  If you want your application to show up on this website, publish it in the Android Market.

Comment: thank u for your response but i have already publish my app in android market but it doesn't appears in app brain.

Comment: I have seen AppBrain take up to a week to scrape new applications and display them on the page.

Comment: True, this seems to have been added.  If the OP moves the accepted mark, I can delete this.

Answer (score 7):

You can add an app to AppBrain here: http://www.appbrain.com/info/addapp

It will then fetch the latest information from the Google Play Market and add the app to the AppBrain site.